# iOS Twitter login without reverse auth

Tags: ios, twitter, authentication, webview, safari

I have found an example that shows login via Twitter using [Reverse Auth](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/using-reverse-auth). But I want something like this

[image: Open in WebView]

**NOTE: *NOT* open in Safari**

Is there any example or tutorial talking about this?

Comment: use this library.working perfectly for me https://github.com/fhsjaagshs/FHSTwitterEngine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this library to do web view Oauth login, this should make the job done: 
https://github.com/fhsjaagshs/FHSTwitterEngine

Comment: Wow! Exactly what I want. Thanks